# Simple but too many positional arguments for method call

Tags: python, class, methods, self

1. Would anyone explain why the `TypeError` is

   > fib() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

   when I'm only giving it ONE argument => `self.fib(self.n - 1)` !
2. Also, while keeping the instantiation of the class, can you suggest your solution to fix this?
3. I feel the "self" is being used too much, especially with the more methods I add. Can that be improved?

Just trying to wrap my head around some basics! All feedback is appreciated.

```
class math_func:
    def __init__(self, n: "int" = 6, output: "list" = []):
        self.n = n
        self.output = output

    def fib(self):
        print("Current output is:", self.output)
        if self.n == 0:
            return self.output
        else:
            if len(self.output) < 2:
                self.output.append(1)
                self.fib(self.n - 1)
            else:
                last = self.output[-1]
                second_last = self.output[-2]
                self.output.append(last + second_last)
                self.fib(self.n - 1)
            return self.output

first_func = math_func(n=9)
print(first_func.fib())
```

Answer (score 3):

The first argument of a method is `self`, which refers to the *object* the method is being called on.  If, as it appears, you wish to pass an argument (`n`, it looks like), you need to include that in the method's signature.

Answer (score 1):

This function takes one argument `self`, but this line: `self.fib(self.n - 1)` attempts to pass 2: `self` and `self.n - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

When u first call fib() in

> print(first_func.fib())

you pass no args except the implicit self. in the next call you pass 1 arg which makes it 2 (including the implicit self)

> self.fib(self.n - 1)

This provides the TypeError: fib() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

about the Fibonacci, a simpler implementation :

```
def fib(n):
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))
```

Comment: Thanks. yea, that's correct but on this one, I was playing w dynamic programming instead of recursion. Also, with instantiation...

Answer (score 1):

A type error can mean many things. In this case it means that you have passed too many arguments into a function. It looks like you are calling self.fib with a parameter. You have defined it only with self as a parameter. From the way you have written your code, it seems that you think that you need to pass self as an argument. The truth is that it is an invisible parameter that is already passed when you call the function.

Do something like this:

```
class math_func:
        def __init__(self, '''...'''):
            #...
        def fib(self):
            #...
            self.n = self.n - 1
            self.fib()
```

or

```
class math_func:
        def __init__(self, '''...'''):
            #...
        def fib(self):
            #...
            self.fib2(self.n -1)
        def fib2(self, n: int):
            #...
            #same thing as fib with slight changes
```

or

```
class math_func:
    def __init__(self, '''...'''):
        #...
    def fib(self, n: int):
        #...
        self.fib(self.n - 1)
    def getN(self):
        return self.n

fib = math_func('''...''')
print(fib.fib(fib.getN())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include n as fib's agrument

```py
def fib(self, n):
...
```

Also a little addition: If you define recursive functions you should consider using lru_cache decorator for performance improvement.

```py
from functools import lru_cache

...

@lru_cache(500) # 500 is the cache size
def fib(self, n):
...
```